# React-native connection errors

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to start a new project in React Native but I'm getting errors when I try to launch iOS Simulator. I have not edited the index.ios.js. I'm using iOS Simulator to run the project, and the error in the emulator is 'Could not connect to development server...'

> > Looking for JS files in    /Users/jeff/Documents/TestApp
>
> ERROR  EACCES, permission denied '/Users/jeff/.babel.json'
>   {"errno":-13,"code":"EACCES","path":"/Users/jeff/.babel.json","syscall":"open"}
>   Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/jeff/.babel.json'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.:500:18)
>       at Object.fs.writeFileSync (evalmachine.:1099:15)
>       at save (/Users/jeff/Documents/TestApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/cache.js:35:19)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3
>
> See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
>   for common problems and solutions. evalmachine.:565
>   fs.write = function(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback) {
>                                                    ^ Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/jeff/.babel.json'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.:500:18)
>       at Object.fs.writeFileSync (evalmachine.:1099:15)
>       at process.save (/Users/jeff/Documents/TestApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/cache.js:35:19)
>       at process.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at process.exit (node.js:600:17)
>       at process. (/Users/jeff/Documents/TestApp/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js:143:11)
>       at process.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at process._fatalException (node.js:236:26) Process terminated. Press  to close the window

Comment: Do you have `Watchman` installed, and are you using `iojs`?

Comment: Yes installed watchman with brew. I had to install iojs separately

Comment: I uninstalled everything then reinstalled brew, iojs, nvm, and npm. Now when I try to run a project on the emulator I get this error: packager.sh: line 19: node: command not found

Answer (score 21):

I had fixed this problem, and execute the following command

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.babel.json
```

and then re-init the react-native project, it will be successful.

Comment: in a docker container I had to set the environment variable BABEL_CACHE_PATH to "/whatever/babel.json". node will pick it up from: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/1559/files

Answer (score 0):

You can try just

```
nvm alias default iojs-v2
```

If that doesn't work try going through all the steps in the [installation guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#requirements) again. Then in your project folder

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm i
```

In Xcode remove `RCTWebSocketDebugger` from your libraries: 
`YourProject > Libraries > RCTWebSocketDebugger`

Then in Xcode `Product -> Clean` and try building again

Answer (score -1):

Giving the admin permissions to the path `~/.babel.json` should help. Try with this command:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.babel.json
```